# THREE.js CTMLoader Progress

Tags: three.js, progress, loader

Does anyone know if there is a CTMLoader progress script anywhere?  Or can someone point me in the right direction to build one?  Like where inside the loader I can implement a progress call?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any examples anywhere, but I've just implemented it in my own app. It's just a matter of adding .onprogress to the xhr. I added this at line 100 of CTMLoader.js:

```
    xhr.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
        console.log('Progress: ' + (progressEvent.total / progressEvent.loaded))
    };
```